# Automapper with object of objects and resolvers

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper

I am trying to use automapper to map an EF entity to an modelview for MVC. I found a lot of examples everywhere for map when using the old static version of automapper but when doing the new interfaced based no clean cut examples is available.

In my structure the UserLog object has an property of ApplicationUser and UserLog should be mapped against the UserLogsModel

In my *App_start* folder I have a

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static IMapper mapper;

    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<UserLog, UserLogsModel>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Name, q => q.MapFrom(s => s.User.FirstName + " " + s.User.LastName))
            .ForMember(d => d.UserName, q => q.ResolveUsing<UserNameResolver>());
    });

        mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var source = new UserLog();
        var dest = mapper.Map<UserLog, UserLogsModel>(source);

        var source2 = new List<UserLog>();
        var dest2 = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserLog>>(source2);



        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
```

}

And then I also have the UserNameResolver in the same folder and namespace

```
public class UserNameResolver : IValueResolver<UserLog, UserLogsModel, string>
{
    public string Resolve(UserLog source, UserLogsModel d, string dest, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source.User.UserName;
    }
}
```

The Resolver won't work. I don't even get why the UserLogsModel need to be a part of the resolver since it doesn't add anything to the solution. Any suggestions on how I should write this? It looks that I missing some core knowledge here. My guess is also that the AutoMapperConfig should not look as it does.

When I changed the initialization to static and replace the Automapperconfig with

```
   Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<UserLog, UserLogsModel>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Name, q => q.MapFrom(s => string.Join(" ", s.User.FirstName, s.User.LastName)))
            .ForMember(d => d.UserName, q => q.MapFrom(s => s.User.UserName))
            .ForMember(d => d.Email, q => q.MapFrom(s => s.User.Email));

        });
```

It works but still no resolver

Comment: Looks like you could just use `.ForMember(d => d.UserName, q => q.MapFrom(s => s.User.UserName));` instead of the ValueResolver?

Comment: .. however I do find following the AutoMapper naming conventions to be helpful, where that would be `.ForMember(dest => dest.UserName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.User.UserName));`

Comment: I have read that to be able to handle null values you need to have ValueResolver to make it possible to check that. But since its a string with an underlying database thats mapped on to it. I wonders if that should be check for null values even...

Comment: Tried you suggestion stuartd and It didnt work. Seems that I need valueresolver since "opt.MapFrom(src => src.User.UserName))" fails. And UserName have values. If I remove the mapping and use the entity directly in the page it values shows.

Comment: Perhaps that's the same reason the resolver didn't work, as it looks correct.

Comment: When I changed the initlization to static and replace the Automapperconfig with
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<UserLog, UserLogsModel>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Name, q => q.MapFrom(s => string.Join(" ", s.User.FirstName, s.User.LastName)))
                .ForMember(d => d.UserName, q => q.MapFrom(s => s.User.UserName))
                .ForMember(d => d.Email, q => q.MapFrom(s => s.User.Email));

            });

It works but still no resolver

Comment: Thanks for your help @stuartd